# tabulator: demo shows a blank page

Tags: tabulator

I have copied over the 'basic' demo from the Tabulator page and made the changes necessary so that it looks at the javascript and css files locally but it just shows me a blank page. Below is the source of the page from my site. Why is the page coming up blank?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <link href="t/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="example-table"></div>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="t/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        //sample data
                        var tabledata = [
                            {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:"12/08/2017"},
                            {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
                            {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
                            {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
                            {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
                        ];

                        $("#example-table").tabulator({
                            height:200, // set height of table to enable virtual DOM
                            data:tabledata, //load initial data into table
                            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
                            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                                {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:150},
                                {title:"Age", field:"age", sorter:"number", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", sorter:"string", sortable:false},
                                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
                            ],
                            rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
                                alert("Row " + id + " Clicked!!!!");
                            },
                        });
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**

I downloaded version 4.2.1 and pulled the example right from the homepage. STILL NOT WORKING. I have been tinkering with this (on and off) for months now and have YET to see data in a table. I see all the examples on the website that are working but, when I copy them to MY server, they don't show any data.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        data:tabledata,           //load row data from array
        layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
        responsiveLayout:"hide",  //hide columns that dont fit on the table
        tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
        addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
        history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
        pagination:"local",       //paginate the data
        paginationSize:7,         //allow 7 rows per page of data
        movableColumns:true,      //allow column order to be changed
        resizableRows:true,       //allow row order to be changed
        initialSort:[             //set the initial sort order of the data
                {column:"name", dir:"asc"},
        ],
        columns:[                 //define the table columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input"},
                {title:"Task Progress", field:"progress", align:"left", formatter:"progress", editor:true},
                {title:"Gender", field:"gender", width:95, editor:"select", editorParams:{"Male":"male", "Female":"female"}},
                {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100, editor:true},
                {title:"Color", field:"col", width:130, editor:"input"},
                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", width:130, sorter:"date", align:"center"},
                {title:"Driver", field:"car", width:90,  align:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean", editor:true},
        ],
});

</script>
```

If I am missing anything or need to change something PLEASE be specific (don't just say 'look at this example on the website')

Comment: Which version of Tabulator are you using here?

Comment: I downloaded v4.1 but I'm not sure for which version this example was created.

Comment: Is there a better demo file I could start with? I'm still evaluating whether or not I want to use your framework (it looks great!) but I can't get this demo to work so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The demo you are using is for v3.5 which is not compatible with the v4.1 codebase you are using

If you go to the [Quickstart Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/quickstart) it will take you through how to set things up for version 4.1

The website is jam packed full of working examples for you to play with